# What exactly do "channel" refer to in opencv?

Tags: opencv

i don't understand when opencv documentation mention the term "channel" . Does it mean the channel as in digital image ? or it is something else ?

Comment: typically the number of channels of matrix/image elements are meant. To represent a RGB imsge for example you could either choose a 3D matrix (size: width x height x 3) or you could choose a 2d matrix where each element has 3 channels. Matrix elements typically have type VecNT where N is the number of channels and T is the type-abbreviation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So as OpenCV is an image processing Library, So A given image can be assumed as 2D matrix with each element as a pixel. Now since there are various types of image formats like `Gray`, `RGB` or `RGBA`, etc. each format is different as to how many colors it(pixel) can support. For example the pixels of `Gray` image take values in range `0-255` so to represent each gray pixel we need single `uchar` value, so it has single channel, similarly the pixels of `RGB` image can take values from `0-16777216`  and to represent each `RGB` pixel, we need 3 `uchar` values, (256^3 = 16777216), hence it is 3 channels, similarly `RGBA` has 4 channels, the last channel is used for storing the alpha(transparency) value.