# image.channels() not counting correctly for 2 channel tif images in opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am newbie to using opencv with c++. I have a code where I read tif images and count the number of channels and number of layers in the tif image. I have used Mat.channels() to calculate the number of channels in the image and if the channels are more than 1, then I have used cv::split() to split the image into corresponsing channel images. The code works perfectly for 1 channel and 3 channel images. But for 2 channel images (I have also cross verified and confirmed that the image is 2 channel with Halcon), Mat.channels() gives the output as 1. And for 4 channel images, Mat.channels() gives 4 but cv::split() doesn't split the images properly. I would like to know if I am doing anything wrong here and why this is happening.

Any help or input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please read the link:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43822390/what-exactly-do-channel-refer-to-in-opencv

Comment: The supported image formats are Gray, RGB, and RGBA. If there are 4 channels, the 4th channel is the alpha channel, i.e. the transparency